# UINavigationController: initWithRootViewController: returning nil

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to setup a Navigation Controller for the first time and it is consistently returning nil, even though I can directly set the view controller to the window and all is well.
The code from the App Delegate is pretty standard:

```
//  Set the root view controller and display the window
_vcMain = [ [ ViewControllerMain alloc ] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil ];
self.navController = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController: _vcMain ];

//  self.window.rootViewController = _vcMain;  <-- Works
self.window.rootViewController = _navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return( YES );
```

ViewControllerMain is a subclass of UIViewController.

Is there a way of getting an error about what went wrong with the initialisation?  Any help would be appreciated as this shouldn't really be causing any issues  :-(

Comment: nib name nil?? ve you created xib?

Comment: Did you try setting the nibName?

Comment: D'oh; I messed up the @synthesize..  thanks for replying.  It has been a long day...

Comment: @Roddy if you have found a solution to your question, please submit it as an answer and mark it as accepted.